# NULL Pointer Returned by fopen - but no Errors

Tags: c++, pointers, null, fopen

I'm attempting to use `fopen` to open a file. I'm using an absolute path, the file does exist, and it's not corrupt. Also, all system users have full access to read/write the file.

```
const char* filename = "absolute\\path\\to\\file.something";
const char* mode = "rb";

FILE* file = fopen(filename, mode);

std::cout << "Errors: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
std::cout << "File errors: " << ferror(file) << std::endl;
perror(filename);

fclose(file);
```

All the error reporting shows no errors at all, yet `fopen` returns a null pointer. If I try to seek the file I get an `Access Violation 0x00000014, which, from what I've read, just means the pointer is null. :)

Error reports:

- `strerror(errno)`: "No error"
- `ferror(file)`: 0
- `perror(filename)`: "No error"

What other error checking could I possibly do? What's the next thing to try in order to figure this out?

To explain why I'm mixing C with C++:
I'm going to be using a C library which needs a FILE handle, otherwise I would've used fstream. So, the hope is to get this fopen working so I can pass the FILE over to the C library. The rest of my project is in C++. :)

---

UPDATE #1:

This check **does not** work for me:

```
if (file == NULL) {
    std::cout << "File is null" << std::endl;
}
```

This check **does** work for me:

```
if (file->_ptr == NULL) {
    std::cout << "_ptr is null" << std::endl;
}
```

---

UPDATE #2:

This shows the `FILE` as **not** `NULL`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(file) << std::endl;
```

This shows the `FILE`'s pointer as `00000000` (`NULL`):

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(file->_ptr) << std::endl;
```

---

UPDATE #3:

@chux has enlightened me. The file does indeed open correctly, as I just did a quick check and printed to the console the contents of the file and it didn't fail at all.

I was misinterpreting the `file->_ptr` as showing `NULL` to be the "true" value of the pointer. However, even though stepping through the code in the debugger shows it as `NULL`, I was able to print the contents of the file - it was opened successfully all along!

Perhaps this question should be started again - perhaps elsewhere - due to the fact I now realise this is not an `fopen` issue, but that of the library I'm passing the `FILE` to. The library is experiencing the exception that originally brought my attention to checking if the file opened correctly, and eventually to seeing (in debugging) that the `_ptr` shows as `NULL` - which was misleading to me.

How embarrassing. :)

Comment: Code does not indicate `file` is `NULL`.  `"absolute\\path\\to\\file.something"` does not look like an absolute path.  Perhaps `"C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\file.something"`?

Comment: Do `cout << static_cast<void*>(file) << endl;` after the `fopen` and confirm that it is really, truly NULL.  Also, which platform?  I gather Windows from the backslash, but which version and compiler?

Comment: Is the file open in another mode which may be choking the access?

Comment: Also, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39415120/edit) to show the seek code that is actually exhibiting the error :) .

Comment: `std::cout << "Errors: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;` is not C code as tagged.  Make the language of your post and code consistent.  Consider rolling back to C and appending `printf("%lx\n", (unsigned long) file);`  (Casting to an integer as likely this is a windows compiler that may lack `%p` support)

Comment: @cxw Suggesting C++ code to a C question has confused the post.

Comment: Please someone decide whether this is a c++ or a c question!

Comment: Why use `fopen()` in C++ ?  I would expect some stream usage.

Comment: @chux I'm definitely using an absolute path. I just don't want to share it on the web. So, trust me. :P

Also, I'm using a C library which needs a FILE handle. So, to save converting an fstream to FILE it's easier just to use fopen().

Comment: @chux OP used `cout` so I used `cout`.  I actually didn't look at the tags --- I was more interested in the OP's answer to my question.

Comment: @iharob I think C, seeing as fopen is C? :)

Comment: I don't understand why you say `file` is `NULL` if you don't check. Please post code that does reproduce your problem. If `fopen()` fails you should see why through `errno`, but there is no evidence of failure in your code, when `fopen()` succeeds `errno` will not be set, you only need to check `errno` `if (file == NULL) ... `

Comment: @all Just edited the post explaining why mixing C with C++.

Comment: @iharob I check by stepping through the debugger.

Comment: @iharob ...and my code is the same as above, apart from the path to the file of course (it's a real path). lol

Comment: Why does code lack  the result of `file == NULL`?  The most obvious reason for no error and  "fopen returns a null pointer." is incorrect because `file` **is not** `NULL` .  Add code the shows the pointer value or the compare result.  Note: If it _was_ `NULL`, `fclose(NULL)` is UB.

Comment: @chux I do have a check for that in my original code, but that always passes and is never seen as NULL. However, stepping through the code with breakpoints lets me see that it is actually a null pointer.

Also, just checked:

if (file->_ptr == NULL) { ... }

Now it sees it's NULL. :)

Comment: By not posting true code, the question is unnecessarily complicated.  AKAIK, the file name is reserved by the OS, but you somehow created it.  The file is already opened for exclusive access by someone else.  The unposted check for NULL is inadequate.

Comment: With recent update, why code `if (file->_ptr == NULL) {`?  - Where did _that_ come from?  That is not specified to have anything to do with the success/fail of `fopen()`.  Just use the right check `if (file == NULL) {` and avoid the phrase "does not work" .  Explain "This check does not work for me:"  What was expected, what was noted.

Comment: @cxw The output of the code you suggested gave me: "015DA3B0". The pointer that resides inside the FILE object is null though. So, `cout << static_cast<void*>(file->_ptr) << endl;` is null. :)

I'm on Windows 10, Visual Studio Express 2013, `_MSC_VER`: 1800.

Comment: @chux The code posted shows exactly what I'm doing with the file, the only thing I've changed is the `filename` and I do actually have the NULL check. Plus, the NULL check isn't correct (see update to my post).

Answer (score 2):

You need to save `errno` before invoking any functions that may change it:

```
FILE* file = fopen(filename, mode);
int error_code = errno;
std::cout << "Errors: " << strerror(error_code) << std::endl;
```

In this particular code `std::cout << "Errors: "` may change `errno`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's made difference to the error code.

Comment: @Aaron Did you intend to say "fortunately"?

Comment: There are no functions that would modify `errno`. Also, there is no check for `file` against `NULL`. So I think it would be good to check first,

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Sorry, I meant to say that it made no difference to the error code - it's still zero.

Answer (score 1):

OP's code returns a non-`NULL` pointer per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39415120/null-pointer-returned-by-fopen-but-no-errors?noredirect=1#comment66157617_39415120), indicating a successful `fopen()` result.

Further OP states the file *does* exist

With no error in opening, no errors are expected using `errno`, `strerror(errno)` `ferror(file)`.

The inner contents of `*file` have no specification for code to use.
Best to not code `if (file->_ptr == NULL) {`

Comment: I think I may have posted the wrong question then, **oops!**.I assumed there was an issue there. However, after attempting to run through the file and print its contents to the console it did so fine.

I think my issue is actually related to something else then - the library I'm using to send the file to. It's an OggVorbis file and I'm using the Ogg DLLs to create my own player. The `fseek()` in the `_fseek64_wrap` vorbis method throws the exception.

Comment: The moderators will probably burn this post lol Don't blame them if they do.

Comment: I concentrated on just opening the file because I misunderstood what was happening with `_ptr` in the `FILE` and thought, because it was showing as `NULL`, that it was indeed `NULL` and there was an issue opening the file.

Comment: @Aaron you've learned something useful :) .  chux is right - never look inside the `FILE` structure (unless you're writing your own implementation of the standard library :) ).  Now that you are closer to the real problem, you can post a different question *including the relevant code*.  Good luck!

Comment: @Aaron to be clear "This shows the FILE's pointer as 00000000 (NULL):" is not correct.  That shows a field inside `file` is `NULL`.  The value of that field should be opaque to your code.  do not use it.

Comment: @cxw It's quite embarrassing, but I agree: at least I've learnt something! :P

Comment: @chux I'm starting to understand where I went wrong and misled myself because of this. Thank you for explaining that I should ignore these things. I usually do console logs of things for checking as I go, and I don't know why I didn't do that in the first place. :)

Comment: @Aaron Future ref: Best to post compilable code, user input, output, and expected output that itself demonstrates the problem - it saves us all time.  Problem description is often _ignored_ when it does not agree or is not backed up with code - code speaks louder than words.  Also, best to stick to one language as able.  In this case, I trusted the code results more than the problem description.

Comment: @chux You were right to trust the code. I just assumed it was an issue with opening the file - due to my lack of understanding of how the `FILE` will/should look as we step through with breakpoints.

You certainly hit the nail on the head and made me rethink what was going on! You also taught me a good lesson! :P

In future, I will post far more information on the issue. Prior to that, I will be sure to examine what's happening in more detail before asking questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion here, it seems that I've misunderstood what's been happening.

In my case, there is no issue with opening the file. This is either an issue with the OggVorbis library (see original post: UPDATE: #3), or my approach to compiling the library, or both.

My apologies for any inconvenience caused by this irrelevant question, but I hope someone will also learn what I have learnt because of it:

1. Don't check the `file->_ptr` for `NULL`, the `FILE` itself *will* be `NULL` if `fopen` fails
2. If you're using a library that handles a `FILE` and throws an exception, check that the `FILE` can be opened and its contents printed to the console
3. If (after testing) you can open and read the file yourself, see it as an issue regarding the library
4. Search Google for similar issues regarding the library
5. If searching fails to find a solution, only then should you post the question
6. When posting the question, give as much detail as possible:

   - Library versions
   - Snippets of your code that should reproduce the issue(s)
   - Details of how you compiled the libraries (if you did)
   - IDE version
   - Operating System and version
   - Details of the error code

This is the post concerning my actual problem: [OggVorbis ov_open() Throws Access Violation Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417913/oggvorbis-ov-open-throws-access-violation-exception)