# OggVorbis ov_open() Throws Access Violation Exception

Tags: c++, windows, fseek, oggvorbis

I'm trying to open an OggVorbis file using the Vorbis SDK/DLLs. `ov_open()` throws an Access Violation exception `0x00000014`. I have checked the file exists: I've opened it with `fopen` and printed the contents to the console just to check - all went fine!

Might not make a difference, but the DLLs have been compiled as *DEBUG Win32*, and my project is compiling under the same configuration.

I'm using an absolute path to the file, for reassurance, and the file does exist. As stated before, I can open and read it myself.

The *.ogg file was rendered using FL Studio at 192kbps, and it also opens and plays fine in Adobe Audition and VLC Media Player.

This is the code I have to open the file and send it to the Vorbis library (the code came from [this](http://forum.devmaster.net/t/openal-lesson-8-oggvorbis-streaming-using-the-source-queue/2895) tutorial):

```
FILE* oggFile;
const char* path = "C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\file.ogg";
const char* openMode = "rb";
int result;

if (!(oggFile = fopen(path, openMode)))
{
    throw std::string("Could not open file.");
}

if ((result = ov_open(oggFile, &oggStream, NULL, 0)) < 0)
{
    // Never gets here
    fclose(oggFile);
    throw std::string("Could not open Ogg stream: ");
}
```

The "Vorbis" code where the exception is thrown:

```
// vorbisfile.c: line #827

static int _fseek64_wrap(FILE *f,ogg_int64_t off,int whence) {
    if(f==NULL)return(-1);
    return fseek(f,off,whence); // Exception thrown here
}
```

At this point, `off == 0` and `whence == 1`.

I do see the method name contains "64". Could this be wanting to read a 64bit encoded file? Or is it trying to run as 64bit when it's actually compiled as 32bit? Or is this not the issue at all? :P

Also, as I followed the tutorial I noticed there were a couple of mistakes in the code that I had to correct. So I'm wondering if the tutorial is "complete" enough, ie: perhaps there is some variable I should `#define`, or something else that's possibly missing prior to sending the opened file to `ov_open` in order for it to be handled accordingly.

Tech Specs:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Express 2013
- `_MSC_VER` 1800
- `libogg.dll` v1.3.2 (current)
- `libvorbis.dll` v1.3.5 (current)

**NOTE:** The downloaded *Vorbis* source code only contained *Solution* and *Project* files up to VS2010. I opened the VS2010 *Solutions* in Visual Studio Express 2013 to compile them in order to attain compatibility with my project. I'm also wondering if this might lead to some issues.

Comment: `fseek(f,off,whence)` takes a `long`.  May want to insure `ogg_int64_t off` is in the range of `long` by testing against `LONG_MAX,LONG_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OggVorbis documentation recommends not using ov_open on windows (https://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/vorbisfile/ov_open.html).

Use ov_open_callbacks instead.

Something like this should work:

```
ov_open_callbacks(oggFile, &oggStream, NULL, 0, OV_CALLBACKS_DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was so simple to fix! I updated my code and it works perfectly! The OggVorbis file plays. Thanks you! :)

Comment: I'll be more inclined to seek out, and read, library documentation and specifications in the future. I think doing so would have saved a lot of time and headaches! :)